# Generic query with Entity Framework ORM

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, architecture

So currently i am writing a specific SQL function to get a specific row from a specific table.

However, I have dozens of tables, and noticed that I am writing these same 'get row' repository functions each time I make a new table.

Is it possible to write a generic function that works for every table, in this case to get a specific row?

Current (Example)

```
   public Purchase GetPurchase(long purchaseId)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(_connStringKey))
        {
            var result = (from p in db.Purchases
                          where p.PurchaseId.Equals(purchaseId)
                          select p).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Generic Example (To give you an idea)

```
  public Object GenericGet (string tableName, string rowName, long rowId)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(_connStringKey))
        {
            var result = (from p in db.tableName
                          where p.rowName.Equals(rowId)
                          select p).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: You should probably look up Entity Framework or generating .tt templates in C# to get started.

Comment: Why do you have dozens of tables to hold purchases?

Comment: I have one table to hold purchases, but dozens of tables that require getting a specific row.

Comment: Edited the Question so it would be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `reflection` but it is not a good approach. Instead of this, you could try something using the generics aspects of the language, and make sure what you want, for sample:

```
public T Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    where T : class
{
   T result;
   using (var db = new DbContext(_connStringKey))
   {
      result = db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filter);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Remember that the `T` must be a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.103).aspx), so, define a constraint for `class`

Then, you could try this:

```
var product = Get<Product>(p => p.Name == "Something");
var supplier = Get<Supplier>(p => p.Sector == "Manufacturing");
```

Comment: Unfortunately when trying it I get an error with regards to the Db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filter). The error is at the Db.Set. "The Type T must be a reference type."

Comment: Yes, It was missing the `constraint`, see my updates.